# Tel link from email doesn't work yahoo webmail

Tags: android, email, outlook, browser

HI: I have some similar issue.

I have a html email developed and here is a tel link. here is the code:

```
<table width="155" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="155" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:13px; line-height:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#827f7f; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
   <span style="font-size:12px; line-height:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#827f7f;">Call us at:</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="155" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:15px; line-height:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
   <a class="black_link" href="tel:+18558550855" description="F_TXT_CALL" style="font-size:15px; line-height:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">
    <span style="font-size:15px; line-height:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">1-855-8550-855</span>
   </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The thing is that my "tel:" protocol isn't working for yahoo and outlook.com webmail clients. and I found some for this and this site tell that yahoo doesn't allow this kind of links ( http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3571/using-phone-numbers-in-html-email/ )

But I can't share this link because, tel protocols works well on Outlook 2007/2010. And realy try to find some fix but with out any answer... 
**Does anyone know why yahoo doesn't allow this tel protocol? or if there is other like "callto" that I can use with compatibility for all webmails clients ?**

Here are my test clients:

**Desk:** Outlook 2007/2010 Outlook 2003 Apple Mail Windows Live Mail

**Webmail:** Hotmail Yahoo! Mail Gmail

**Mobile email clients:** iPhone Android 2.2 Android +4.0

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately until all the players agree to support tel links you can't use them in mass emails. To add insult to injury, if you don't include the tel link some phones (iPhone especially) will make it a link anyway and use default styling (dark blue underlined) woe be to you if you are using a dark background.

So the creative workaround is to link to a contact page of some sort with the phone # prominently displayed so phone users will only have to click twice which is far easier then copying text and IMHO better then presenting a broken link.